# Spinner with wrap_content and max_width

Tags: android

Is it possible, either through xml or otherwise, to have a spinner wrap it's content up to a certain max width?

Answer (score 0):

Set android:layout_width to "fill_parent", "wrap_content" or set fixed width in dip (eg. 300dip)

Comment: I actually want to have both "wrap_content" as well as a max width, so if there are more than say 15 characters it does not expand past a set point.

Comment: Use the Layout's layout_width to handle the max width and Spinner's layout_width to handle wrap_content